# Let $f(x)=\frac{\alpha x}{x+1},x\neq-1.$Then for what value of $\alpha$ is $f(f(x))=x?$

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f(x)=\frac{\alpha x}{x+1},x\neq-1.$Then for what value of $\alpha$ is $f(f(x))=x?$

---

Given
$f(f(x))=x$
$\Rightarrow f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ means we need to find the point where the function and its inverse intersect and such points are found on the line $y=x$ so 
we need to solve $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)=x$
$\frac{\alpha x}{x+1}=x$ gives $x=0$ and $x=\alpha-1$
I found $f(f(x))=\frac{\alpha^2x}{(\alpha+1)x+1}$
Then solving,$\frac{\alpha^2x}{(\alpha+1)x+1}=x$
Solving the equation gives $\alpha=\pm1$

But in my book only $\alpha=-1$ is given answer.I dont understand why $\alpha=1$ value is rejected. Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: You can composite and resolve the equation...

Comment: If f(f(x))=x , is false that f=f-1= x necessarily

Comment: I have edited the question after solving the equation but i am still stuck and final answer is elusive.

Comment: Show us how you came up with $\alpha=1$ in the first place. When I solve $\frac{\alpha^2x}{(\alpha+1)x+1}=x$ I only arrive at $\alpha=-1$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solving $\frac{\alpha^2x}{(\alpha+1)x+1}=x\ \ $ *for all* $x$ gives:
$$\frac{\alpha^2x}{(\alpha+1)x+1}=x \iff \alpha^2x=(\alpha+1)x^2+x\iff (\alpha+1)x^2+x-\alpha^2x=0$$
$$\iff x\left((\alpha+1)x+1-\alpha^2\right)=0 \ \forall x \implies \left((\alpha+1)x+1-\alpha^2\right)=0$$
$$\implies (\alpha+1)x=0\ \ \wedge\ \ 1-\alpha^2=0$$
Obviously $\alpha=-1$ is the only $\alpha$ that satisfies.

Comment: Why does $(\alpha+1)x+1-\alpha^2=0$ changes to $(\alpha+1)x=0$ and inverted V $1-\alpha^2=0$?What does inverted V means?Does it mean "and"?Do you mean if sum of two quantities is zero,then they should individually be zero.@Eric S

Comment: the $\wedge$ symbol (`\wedge`) means 'and at the same time'. So what I mean is, if $(\alpha+1)x+1-\alpha^2$ should equal zero **for all** $x$, then both $\alpha+1$ should equal zero and $1-\alpha^2$ should equal zero. Look upon it as $ax+b=0$, with $a$ and $b$ constants. If $ax+b$ should equal zero for all $x$, the only possibility is both $a$ and $b$ are zero. :)

Comment: I got it,thank you@Eric S

Answer (score 1):

$$f(f(x)) = \frac{\alpha^2x}{\alpha x+x+1}=x$$
$$\alpha x^2 + x^2+x-\alpha^2x=0$$
$$x(1+\alpha)(x-\alpha+1)=0$$
From here it's pretty simple to see what values work.